# Drop table en un trigger MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, trigger, tablas

quisiera saber si existe la posibilidad de tener la sentencia
"DROP TABLE TABLATEMPORAL" usando MySQL dentro de un trigger, ya que al intentar guardar el trigger con dicha sentencia me sale el siguiente error:

"There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database"

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `guardarResultadosFyS` 
AFTER INSERT ON `mdl_feedback_completed` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

set @existe = (exists (select * from  mdl_feedback_completed fc
    join mdl_feedback_item fi where 
    label in ('Activo/Reflexivo' , 'Secuencial/Global' , 'Sensitivo/Intuitivo' , 'Visual/Verbal')
    and fc.feedback = fi.feedback and   fc.feedback = 3 limit 1));

if @existe !=0 then

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_resultado AS
    SELECT userid, username, fb.course as idcourse, c.feedback, concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname ) as Nombre,
    count(value) as valor, if(value = 1, 
                            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(label, '/',  1), '/', -1), 
                           SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(label, '/',  2), '/', -1)) as dimension
    FROM mdl_feedback_item d 
     JOIN mdl_feedback_value f 
     JOIN mdl_feedback_completed c
     JOIN mdl_feedback fb
     JOIN mdl_user u
    WHERE c.userid = new.userid and c.feedback = new.feedback and c.id = f.completed and u.id = c.userid and c.feedback = fb.id and
    label in ('Activo/Reflexivo' , 'Secuencial/Global' , 'Sensitivo/Intuitivo' , 'Visual/Verbal')
    and d.id = f.item group by  label,  VALUE, nombre;

    create temporary table tmp_resultadoPivote as
        select 
        userid,
        username,
        idcourse,
        Nombre ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dimension = 'Visual' THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS 'Visual' ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dimension = 'Verbal' THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS 'Verbal',
        SUM(CASE WHEN dimension = 'Secuencial' THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS 'Secuencial' ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dimension = 'Global' THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS 'Global' ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dimension = 'Sensitivo' THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sensitivo' ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dimension = 'Intuitivo' THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS 'Intuitivo' ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dimension = 'Activo' THEN Valor ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Activo' ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dimension = 'Reflexivo' THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS 'Reflexivo' 
        from tmp_resultado;

    create temporary table tmp_resultadoResta as
    select userid, username, idcourse, Nombre, 
    (Visual - Verbal) as 'Visual_Verbal' , #visualverbal
    (Secuencial - Global) as 'Secuencial_Global', #secuencialglobal
    (activo - reflexivo) as 'Activo_Reflexivo' , #activoreflexivo
    (sensitivo - Intuitivo) as 'Sensitivo_Intuitivo'  #sensitivointuitivo
    from tmp_resultadoPivote;


    insert into mdl_feldersilverman
    select idcourse, userid, username, nombre, now() as fecha, Visual_Verbal, Secuencial_Global,
    Activo_Reflexivo, Sensitivo_Intuitivo from tmp_resultadoResta order by idcourse;

    drop table tmp_resultado;
    drop table tmp_resultadoPivote;
    drop table tmp_resultadoResta;

    end if;



END
```

Si elimino la sección donde estan los drop, me deja guardar el script sin problema pero al ejecutarlo una vez funciona bien, pero la segunda me sale el error de que existe la tabla "tmp_resultado"y eso por eso que busco eliminarlas

Answer (score 0):

En algún comentario de stackoverflow he leído que no se puede hacer drop de una tabla temporal en un trigger pero no consigo encontrarlo en la documentación. En principio, las tablas temporales se borran automáticamente cuando se cierra la conexión, pero eso puede que no ocurra en mucho tiempo si usas un pool de conexiones en una aplicación web, por ejemplo

Puedes probar a

- Borrar las tablas temporales antes de volver a crearlas en lugar de al final: `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_resultado;`
- Usar tablas permanentes y vaciarlas y volver a llenarlas cada vez. Tendrías que cambiar los `CREATE TEMPORARY` por `INSERT INTO` y el resultado vendría a ser el mismo
- Usar cursores. Te creas cursores para guardar los datos que vas a tratar en cada consulta y los recorres para completar los datos que necesitas para la tabla final